# PHP Insert form using Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to PHP and mysql. I have created a form which accepts some inputs from the user and I want this inputs to be inserted into the mysql using stored procedure.

Hurray I got this, now form data is inserting into the mysql using stored procedure.

**dbconn.php**

```
<?php
// Set connection variables.
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pwd  = "root";
$db   = "eservice";
// Connect to mysql server
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pwd,$db);
/* Check if any error occured */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to mysql : " . mysqli_connect_error();
exit;
}
?>
```

**Add.php**

```
<?php
// If the form was submitted.
if($_POST)
{
    // Connect to db.   
include 'dbconn.php';
    // Retrieve data from form. 
    $srn = $_POST['srn'];
    $client = $_POST['client']; 
    $type   = $_POST['type'];
    $fy     = $_POST['fy']; 
    $category = $_POST['category'];     
    $sd     = $_POST['sd']; 
    $fd     = $_POST['fd'];
    $assignto = $_POST['assignto'];
    $edoc = $_POST['edoc'];
    $current = date('m/d/Y');
   $date = strtotime("+".$edoc." days", strtotime($current));
$ecd  = date("Y/m/d", $date);
$reviewed = $_POST['reviewed'];
$path   = $_POST['path'];
    // Stored procedure code
    if(!$mysqli->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addproc") 
|| !$mysqli->query("CREATE PROCEDURE addproc
(IN client varchar(50), IN type varchar(30), IN fy INT, IN category varchar(30), IN sd varchar(80), 
IN fd varchar(80), IN assignto varchar(50), IN edoc date, IN reviewed varchar(40), IN upload varchar(100)) 
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO main(client, type, fy, category, sd, fd, assignto, edoc, reviewed, upload) VALUES(client, type, fy, category, sd, fd, assignto, edoc, reviewed, upload); 
END; "))     
{
    echo "Stored procedure creation failed : (" .$mysqli->errno .") " .$mysqli->error;
}
if(!$mysqli->query("CALL addproc('$client','$type','$fy','$category','$sd','$fd','$assignto','$ecd','$reviewed','$path')"))
{
    echo "CALL failed : (" .$mysqli->errno .")" .$mysqli->error;
}
else
{
?>
   <script language="javascript">
alert("Task created successfully" + "\n\n" + " <?php echo "Service Request Number : " .$srn ?>");
    top.location.href = "Home.php"; // Page redirection.
</script>
<?php
}
if(!$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM main"))
{
    echo "SELECT failed : (" .$mysqli->errno .")" .$mysqli->error;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO main(client, type, fy, category, sd, fd, assignto, edoc, reviewed, upload) VALUES('$client', '$type', '$fy', '$category', '$sd', '$fd', '$assignto', '$edoc', '$reviewed', '$upload')";
if(mysqli_query($mysqli,$query))
```

& others.

Comment: I'm using stored procedures.